# Axapta method return List<Array> , how to convert it in c#

Tags: c#, axapta

I have in axapta method that return `List<Array>`. How can I convert it on c# side and for what ? It it possible to convert it to c# `List<ArrayList>` ? I see example for container:

```
        ArrayList magazynierzy = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 1; i <= axContainer.Count; i++)
        {
            magazynierzy.Add(axContainer.get_Item(1).ToString());
        }
```

Comment: That sample looks flawed to start with, in various ways...

Comment: How can a AX method return a `List<Array>`?

AX has a `List` class but it is not C# compatible.
But you can access each member of the list with AX calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are some significant flaws with this question, but taking it that you have some external process return in list of things, they are easily turned into a list of objects. You should define or identify a class that matches the items you have returned, and create a list of these. So something like:

```
        List<string> magazynierzy = new List<string>();
        while(axContainer.ReadNext())
            magazynierzy.Add(axContainer.get_Item(1).ToString());
        return magazynierzy;
```

would give you what you need ( I don't know axapta, so I have no idea how you move through the list ). If you need more complex objects, declare a class of struct for them, with a constructor that will take an axContainer object, or a list of parameters which you can pass various get_Item(n) entries into.